# MYSQLi Multiple Records Outputs Duplicates

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

**Issue:**

I've continuously looked over my code and cannot find why the array is duplicating the data. A single entry into the database has a correct output, however if there is more than one it will duplicate those before it as well as the next one.

**My Code:**

```
global $connection;
        //Query database & retrieve results.
        $search = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE country= "'.$country.'"');
                echo '<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Email</th><th>Country</th></tr>';
                while ($result = $search->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $total[] = $result;
                        foreach ($total as $rows)
                            {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'.stripslashes($rows['username']).'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.stripslashes($rows['email']).'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.stripslashes($rows['country']).'</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
                    }
                echo '</table>';
```

**Output:**

This will return the following form -

```
Username         Email                     Country
exampleUser1 exampleEmail1@example.com United States
exampleUser1 exampleEmail1@example.com United States
exampleUser2 exampleEmail2@example.com United States
```

You can see the first line is repeated then the new entry is there, it will continue on from this the more it goes on.

**Additional Info:**

- This is placed inside of a function and is executed when $_POST['country'] is submitted - $country is just $_POST['country'] with a real_escape_string.
- $connection is just a new mysqli(localhost, user, pass, database) referenced in the script - it is globalised because this is wrapped inside a function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty simple... you add items to an array.. Loop over it and keep adding items to that array and keep looping over it..

Comment: can you show us how are you calling the function ?

Comment: @Naruto So you're say that $result = array('username' => stripslashes($rows['username']), 'email' => stripslashes($rows['email']), 'country => stripslashes($rows['country'])); then I let it repeat in the foreach function until finished?

Comment: @MohamadAttat The referencing is called within' an if statement when an integer becomes active - meaning going from 0 to 1 is will execute. Shown here: if ($active == 1) { searchcountry($country); }

Comment: change foreach ($total as $rows) into foreach($result as $rows), let me know what the result is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    //... Your code
    while ($rows = $search->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows = array_map('stripslashes', $rows);
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$rows['username'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$rows['email'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$rows['country'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    //... Your code
```

if you need to save and return from function this rows just create array $total and add `$total[] = $rows;` after `echo '</tr>';`

Comment: In terms of saving the function to store in an array to use elsewhere and not only to display all results in a table it wont work this way would it. This stores two identical arrays inside one another: Array (Array([0] => exampleUser1, [1] => exampleEmail1@example.com, [3] => United States) Array([0] => exampleUser2, [1] => exampleEmail2@example.com, [3] => United States)) so when I want to use the result of the first account through $row[0] it will echo "exampleUser1exampleUser2" - both of them are joined together, it there a way to separate this? ($total[] creates an array wrapped around it)

Comment: I'm not quite understand the problem. Please, provide some code

Comment: I made it much more informative with a simple layout and all the code as requested here: http://pastebin.com/LcwevSvA

Comment: $total = array();
   while (/*loop condition*/) {
       //...
       $total[] = $row;
   }
   $usernames = array_column($total, 'Username');
   print_r($usernames);
When you use `echo` in the loop without delimiter you will get `texttext`. Try `echo "{$username[0]}\n";` or another delimiter if you still want use `echo` in the loop

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, put the foreach outside your while loop like this:

```
echo '<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Email</th><th>Country</th></tr>';
while ($result = $search->fetch_assoc()) {  
    $total[] = $result;
}

foreach ($total as $rows) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.stripslashes($rows['username']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.stripslashes($rows['email']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.stripslashes($rows['country']).'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Another solution is to just redeclare your $total all the time.. Just keep your code then and do:

```
$total = $result;
```

Comment: How would the foreach grab the data if it is outside the fetching of the database rows? The information is grabbed directly from the database and sorted by country through the query. Could you insert a snippet of what you mean exactly?

Comment: do you even know what [] brackets stands for?

Comment: Your code was an exact duplicate of my own, I asked if you could provide a snippet to get your point across more clearly. [] stands for an array; it's a short form.

Comment: My code isn't and has never been a duplicate of your code.. And if you know what the brackets mean, you could have fixed this yourself with ease..